# Limiting proportions of a matrix "metric"

Tags: probability, matrices, limits, metric-spaces

This question is based on an [earlier posting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Archives/Mathematics/2023_November_3#Limiting_proportions_of_this_matrix_.22metric.22) on the Wikipedia math reference desk, although in that posting the "equals" proportion and the "greater than" proportion were erroneously swapped.

The function $d : \{0,1\}^{n \times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ defined by $d(A, B) = |\det(A-B)|$ is definitively not a metric, as there are matrices that break the triangle inequality. In fact, as the user Kusma pointed out in the previous link, one can construct infinitely many distinct cases thanks to a construction involving Hadamard matrices. Moreover, if one attempts to simulate how "close" $d$ is to being a metric by taking random $A, B, C \in \{0,1\}^{n \times n}$ and finding whether $d(A, C)$ is less than, equal to, or greater than $d(A, B) + d(B, C)$, one gets proportions roughly equal, respectively, to $70\%, 0\%, 30\%$.

There are two questions that I have in regard to this:

1. Does the limit of these proportions actually exist? Some brief testing suggests that this limit may hold regardless of what subset of the reals forms the matrices in the domain of $d$, assuming that entries follow a uniform distribution, and that the subset is not a singleton.
2. If so, there a closed-form expression to describe their values? (In particular, is the proportion of triples $(A, B, C)$ with $|\det(A - C)| = |\det(A - B)| + |\det(B - C)|$ actually $0$?)